# How to avoid copy pasting url from another browser tab in an embedded Spring Boot Angular app

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have an oauth secured spring app with embedded angular. The end points use angular legacy #

```
Sample Urls: 
http://localhost:8081/#/home 
http://localhost:8081/#/demo/16
```

Right now the user can copy paste http://localhost:8081/#/demo/16 into another browser tab, and can create duplicate objects. (system accepts because user already was authorized in the same browser)

I would like to know, how can I avoid this from happening? Is there a way I can add something to my url, that invalidates user request from doing copy paste.

I am thinking of a check in my spring service, but would be nice to disallow copy paste urls in the first place (by using some hashcode etc or something )

Any suggestions/solution  please

Comment: You can’t prevent copy&paste I think.. but maybe you can find out if there is already an existing session and prevent a second one?

Comment: can I make them post or other type?

Comment: No not really. However, if you decide not to use hashes but instead use html5 style url’s, you could fairly easily solve this serverside.

Comment: I can do a check on serverside anyways (with or without hashes ) isn't? But I want to disallow because - a url like  http://localhost:8081/#/demo/16  can be put in a browser after a day or 2, which I want to deny. User should navigate only via button click

Comment: Hash urls do not arrive on the server, that’s the problem.